# a div in a container with a background that stretches to infinity

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a design idea that I'm not exactly sure the best way to go about pulling it off in html and css. Basically I want to do what I've (crudely) drawn in this image:

[image: Crappy design idea]

My basically I want a div to appear some distance down from the top of the page that stretches from infinity, to within the bounds of the container to display some content.  My code looks something like this

```
# html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">

      <div id="content">
        Some text content
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>

# css
div#container {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div#content {
  width: 300px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
}
```

Where the div#content would be the one that has the background that stretches to infinity.  Is this possible to pull off without resorting to altering the background of the  tag? I want to use this on multiple pages within my site, all of which have different heights and distances down from the top, so I'd like to be able to do it without having to switch out the background images for the  tags for these different pages. And the div#content will have variable content length, so using body background images isn't a very elegant solution.  It would be nice to do it without resorting to some kind of absolute positioning as well.

Sorry for rambling, I hope what I am trying to do is clear.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Deleted my answer because it doesn't help you now that i understand your question better. Sorry i don't have a full answer for you.

Comment: That's okay, my apologies for not explaining myself better! I'm not fully sure it's even possible, I was just hoping someone above my paygrade might have some insight.

Comment: A negative margin may do what you want.... but i'm not certain

Comment: That seems to pull the content left with it, outside of the containers bounds.  This might be difficult to do without some calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I whipped [this](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/HAddq/) up.

Just adds a div beneath the content area that matches up with the element you have in the header. It goes on infinitely in both directions. I hope this is what you were trying to achieve.

**EDIT**: As per your request in the comments, I threw [this](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/HAddq/3/) together. It uses jQuery to set the width of the underlying div and its top margin, which is found by getting the top offset of the `fg` div.

Comment: I like where your heads at. It's close. I only want it to stretch to infinity in one direction, and I want to have variable length content both above and below it as well.

Comment: yep that's exactly it.  I thought it would be impossible to do without javascript. awesome.

Comment: @johnnyPando: Glad I could help. I'm sure there's a way to do it without jQuery but it would take a lot more work on your part to figure that out. :)

Answer (score 1):

By "infinity," you mean that div#content appears to go forever to the left of the page and beyond? It can't really go for infinity, but you can certainly give the illusion of that.

*Sigh*.... I am a bit baffled. Maybe because it's midnight and I can't think straight, but I whipped this up:

---

**[Live preview](http://jsfiddle.net/mcyG3/)** *(Feel free to fork this fiddle and play around with it to get it just right.)*

---

Is this close to what you're looking for? I wonder if the most robust way to do this right might involve Javascript (jQuery, specifically). It would really help to know the height of that "content" div, and jQuery might help us with the sizing/positioning of it if the window changes its dimensions.

Comment: Sorry yes, I meant that it appears to go on forever (it just stretches to the left edge of the page).  Your solution is exactly what I am looking for, with one problem, the fixed positioning.  If you add more content (scrolling) the div stays in the same place.  I would like it to scroll with the rest of the content.  See? http://jsfiddle.net/mcyG3/2/ I think jQuery might be the way to go, using it to append an empty div from outside of the container.

Comment: Just remove `position: relative` in div#container and add `position: fixed` in div#content, then you get what you want. See [http://jsfiddle.net/mcyG3/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/mcyG3/3/)

Comment: d'oh! great thanks.  It's late for me too... I wonder if it's possible to make it so the positioning is relative to the content above it. The content is variable, so it would be nice if it could be positioned relatively to the content above it (wouldn't want to cover anything up)

Comment: Very nice, @Genzer. For the horizontal positioning issue (the proper width), you might need jQuery to maintain that... along with knowing the height of that div to pad the elements surrounding it.